# Where is autostart in lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lubuntu

In previous versions it was located in:

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

in 18.10 I can't find it.

What I want is to run a terminal command every time I login in lubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 1):

For a GUI way, it's under Preferences / LXQT settings / Session Settings

Then pick Autostart on the left.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Gnome Ubuntu 18.10 it's `~/.config/autostart`.
Check it for LXDE.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Lubuntu 18.10 uses LXQt and not LXDE.